# How JWT toke expires work ? Logout automatically when token gets expire in node js and angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular

I am very to new `nodejs` and `angular 7` I am using `jwt token` for authentication, I want to redirect automatically to the login page once token get expire. I know similar question have been asked already but I also tired that way I didn't work out for me.

**admin.controller.js**

```
const controller = require("./admin.service");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

module.exports = {
    verifyAdmin: (req, res) => {
        const sign = jwt.sign({admin_user: req.body}, "mysecretkey", {
            expiresIn: "1h"
        })
        req.body.admin_token = sign
        const body = req.body;
        controller.adminLogin(body, (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
                 res.status(500).json({
                    success: 0,
                    message: "Database connection error"
                })
            } else{
                if(result[0].length > 0) {

                    console.log(result[0][0].admin_user)
                    res.json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: result[0],
                        token: sign
                    })
                } else {

                    res.json({
                        success:0,
                        message: "We cannot find it"
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

So someone suggested the using `HttpInterceptor` is good idea for this I used that too but not wokring.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Teacher } from '../shared/teacher.model';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements HttpInterceptor {

  // private adminValidateUrl = "http://localhost:3000/getData";
  private adminValidateUrl = "http://localhost:3000/adminApi/verifyAdmin"
  private verifyAdminToken = "http://localhost:3000/adminApi/getAdminUserName"
  private getTeacherRecordsUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/getTeacherRecords"
  private removeTeacherUrl = "http://localhost:3000/adminApi/removeTeacherRecord"


   subject = new Subject<Teacher[]>();
   teachers: Teacher[] = []
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Token': localStorage.getItem("admin_token")
});

  adminValidation(adminData: any) {
    console.log(adminData)
    return this.http.post<any>(this.adminValidateUrl, adminData)
  }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


  const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("Token", localStorage.getItem("Token")) });

  console.log("Sending request with new header now ...");

  //send the newly created request
  return next.handle(authReq)
  .pipe(err => {
      // onError
      console.log(err);
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log(err.status);
          console.log(err.statusText);
          if (err.status === 401) {
              window.location.href = "/login";
          }
      }
      return Observable.throw(err);
  }) as any;

}
  getAdminUserName() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('admin_token');
    return this.http.get<any>(this.verifyAdminToken, {
      observe: "body",
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    });
  }

  getTeacherRecordsFromDB() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.getTeacherRecordsUrl, {
     observe: "body" 
    })
  }

  removeTeacher(teacher: Teacher) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('admin_token');
      return this.http.post<any>(this.removeTeacherUrl, teacher, {
        observe: "body",
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
      })
  }
}
```

or may be I am not using it right.

so I want a way I which my angular page automatically redirect to login page when token expires with some message of token expire.

Thanks.

Comment: Include a creation timestamp in the token payload along with the expires in.  Sign the token with the creation timestamp, will prevent tampering with the payload.  On the front end you can decode the payload (base64) to get the creation time and add the expires in to the creationg timestamp.  Check if current timestamp is past the calculated expiration timestamp.  Redirect if expired.  You can do this in an Angular Interceptor.

Comment: Yes, the Error Interceptor in Angular is the best approach. Adding a timestamp to the token does not fully help, as you could get outdated in the middle of the request and you are in the same situtation as now. Also, with an outdated JWT token, the API will be returning a 401 (Unauthorized) or 403 (Forbidden), depending on the API's implementation. Maybe you need to check both errors.

Comment: By the way. Are you exposing, in `app.module.ts`, your interceptor (under `providers` section), right? You did not mention this, but otherwise interceptors will not work.

Comment: @JasonWhite and Sergio thanx for replying it's nice idea, but to be honest I am still very confuse how to implement this idea into a code, so can you please help me with code or give some example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use following code inside interceptor to redirect page to login when token expired

```
 return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse
              && (error.status === 403 || error.status === 401)) {
                localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
                window.location.href = '/login';
                return throwError(error);
          } else {
              return throwError(error);

          }
      })
  )
```